# Two codebehind files for one aspx, one VB and one C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Fresh VS2017 Web Site project has a Default.aspx defined this way.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

I have provided it with a Default.aspx.vb file like this:

```
Partial Public Class _Default : Inherits Page

    Public Function Teapot() As Boolean

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

and a Default.aspx.cs file like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);   // There is a breakpoint on this line

        Teapot();            // Error: The name 'Teapot' does not exist
                                       in the current context
    }
}
```

The web site does run, despite the design time error regarding the use of Teapot(), and the breakpoint is flagged as `The breakpoint will not currently be hit.`  It is as if the contents of the C# file are not being included in the project despite the use of a partial class and the inclusion of the following in the web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers></system.codedom>
```

How can I get the contents of both the C# and VB files included in the `_Default` page class?

Comment: You can't combine C# and VB partial classes together - they use different compilers.

Comment: I know, but since they both compile to MSIL I thought that maybe they could be joined at that stage.

Comment: Ok, using the two sub folders of App_Code as described in the article that Ujjwal pointed to in the accepted answer, you CAN write a class in one language that can be called from the _Default class written in the other language (all within the same web project). Not the same as a partial class across two languages, but pretty close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not mix vb and c# within the same project - if you notice in visual studio the project files are either .vbproj or .csproj. You can within a solution - have 1 proj in vb and 1 in c#.

Looks like according to this you can potentially use them both in a web project in the App_Code directory:

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/03/30/ASPNET-20-Use-VBNET-and-C-within-the-App_Code-folder.aspx

But You can use UserControl which will display your data. if you are using CS for default you can get data in backend from your .VB code and display them into the User Control. Else you can get data using Ajax and display those data and events using HTML.
I hope this way you can show all the data and events from .vb and .cs file.

Comment: Ok, using the two sub folders of App_Code you still can't split a partial class between languages, but you CAN define a helper class in one language that can be called from the _Default class written in the other language.

Comment: "You can not mix vb and c# within the same project - if you notice in visual studio the project files are either .vbproj or .csproj." - this rule does not apply to "Visual Studio Websites" (especially those using the old ASP.NET 2.0 (2005-2008) Website model with the `App_Code` directory which is compiled at runtime, not design-time, which **does** mean you can mix C# and VB.NET in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone's still reading this, but you can have a file which uses VB.NET inline code with a C# codebehind.  Your file definition would look like

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Instead of putting your VB code in a codebehind you could put it in a block in the same page inside `<script language = "VB" runat = "server"></script>`  or inside `<% %>` delimiters.